# Is there an equivalent of a file's atime for a MySQL row?

Tags: mysql

This might seem like a weird comparison at first glance, but anyway: every time you *read* a file on Linux, its `atime` is updated.

Is there an equivalent behaviour in MySQL, such as: every time a row is targeted by a SELECT, a *last access time* is updated?

That could prove very useful when storing sessions in the database: you don't want to perform an `UPDATE` after every `SELECT` just to say "this row is fresh".

Any thoughts?

Comment: performance would be pretty crappy if mysql had to update something everytime a row was simply read. and what would constitute a "read"? Simply accessing an indexed field's index value while performining a "where" scan, or when all (part? how much of a part) is returned in a result set?

Comment: @MarcB, also a good reason to mount your datadir with `-o noatime`.

Comment: How is this 'useful when storing sessions'?

Comment: Ok, ok, I knew I was opening a can of worms here ;-) You're right, that's just a silly idea. But I had to ask. @Octopus, you must expire sessions that haven't been **accessed** for more than `x` minutes. If you never write to your session (and optimize it to avoid a useless write when it hasn't changed), but browse the website for an hour, you don't want your session to expire.

Comment: @Bill [This post](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/linux/server-wide-performance-benchmarking.php) concludes that the performance improvement of disabling `atime` is really small. But yep, if you're really looking to push the limits, why not.

Comment: simplest method for expiring sessions is to store a timestamp in the session record. then a periodic job to go through and nuke anything that's older than the expiry period.

Comment: @MarcB, good benchmark article, thanks.

Comment: @Marc Same comment, I don't want to *write* to the session when I just need to read it! But I do want to know the last time it was accessed.